# How to solve error can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Tags: python, string, encoding, utf-8, decoding

Hey please I need help in solving that error. I tried encoding line 24 and Keywords. But that creates another error...
,,,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http

def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packets)


def get_url(packet):
    return packet[http.HTTPRequest].Host + packet[http.HTTPRequest].Path

def get_login_info(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
        load = packet[scapy.Raw].load
        keywords = ["username", "user", "password", "pass", "login"]
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword in load:
                return load

def process_sniffed_packets(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        url = get_url(packet)
        print("[+] HTTP Request >>" + url)

        login_info = get_login_info(packet)
        if login_info:
            print("\n\n[+] Possible username/password >" + login_info + "\n\n")



sniff("wlan0")
```

,,,

**Error**

```
File "packet_sniffer.py", line 32, in <module>
    sniff("wlan0")
  File "packet_sniffer.py", line 7, in sniff
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scapy-2.4.4.dev204-py3.8.egg/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 1058, in sniff
    sniffer._run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scapy-2.4.4.dev204-py3.8.egg/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 1011, in _run
    session.on_packet_received(p)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scapy-2.4.4.dev204-py3.8.egg/scapy/sessions.py", line 108, in on_packet_received
    result = self.prn(pkt)
  File "packet_sniffer.py", line 24, in process_sniffed_packets
    print("[+] HTTP Request >>" + url)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Any idea how to solve it !
I tried many ways to figure it out. I am beginner in python. I lacked in understanding encode/decode/ unicode.

Comment: decode the bytes to a str object

Comment: The geturl function returns bytes, this can not directly be used as a string but has to be casted to a string first. For example if the string is utf-8 decoded use:  print("[+] HTTP Request >>" + url.decode("utf-8"))

Comment: `print()` accepts multiple argument, so you can bypass the problem by writing `print("[+] HTTP Request >>", url)`. The result may not be very pretty, but it will work without an exception, regardless of the type of `url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
print("[+] HTTP Request >>" + url)
```

with

```
print("[+] HTTP Request >>" + url.decode("utf-8"))
```

this will convert `url` to a string.

Comment: Thanks for helping

But I got that error 

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
 
The code works for getting http urls but when I go through https website I get that error.. 
Do you have any idea why is that ?

Comment: Hello, can you provide some more information about the error? Which line triggers it?